# Select all Checked Checkboxes with Name Not Working

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I must have my syntax incorrect, but I am trying to select all checked checkboxes in a table with the name "clone" and loop through them, but my code isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="clone"]:checked').each(function(index, element) {
     alert( index );        
});
```

Also I was planning to append the table with selected rows one by one using the code below where the alert is. Please also let me know if there is a better way to do this as I am fairly new to Jquery.

```
$('#wizard_option_table').append( $(this).parents("tr:first") );
```

Comment: all your checkboxes are having name - clone

Comment: Yes thats correct. I also have a nameset of links named insert and $('a[name="insert"]') seems to select them fine. Are checkboxes different somehow?

Comment: checkboxes should also work the same way...your mentioned jquery in the question is working...what problem u got..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vvVH/18/)

#### jQuery

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"][name="chkbx\\[\\]"]').not(":disabled"));
```

In question try this

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"][name="clone\\[\\]"]').not(":disabled"));
```

Comment: so then would $('input[type="checkbox"][name="clone"]:checked').not(":disabled"); select all that are named "clone"? Because that isn't working either

Comment: can you explain why you used clone[] and not just clone for name attribute

Comment: because multiple checkbox have name attributes value clone[] array type. eg. name="clone[]"

Comment: I am using this selector 'a[name="insert"]' in another part of my code and it seems to work fine to select all links with name insert. Why are checkboxes different?

Comment: you say is also right but, jquery use must write []. PHP no need to write [].

Comment: I am still not sure why adding the brackets made this work, but it did thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first you get the checked element value,then append where you want

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="clone"]:checked').each(function(i){
    alert($(this).val());   // here you get checked check box values
    $('#wizard_option_table tbody').append( '<tr><td>'+$(this).val()+'</td></tr>');
    // you can use append, or prepend http://api.jquery.com/prepend/    
});
```

Comment: How do I only select the ones with name "clone"?

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I had, but it's still not working :(